# SQL: Selecting previously unseen records by a given user

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have a postgres db with a schema like

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
    id integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    author_id integer,
    text text
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    post_id integer,
    ordinal integer DEFAULT 0,
    author_id integer
);
```

Given a specific `author_id`, I want to be able to select a batch of 20 posts that:

1. Does not include a post that has a comment by that author.
2. Is not a post by that author.
3. Does include that 10 most recent comments on that post.

I think point #1 is killing my query times. Up until now I was using an inner query to solve that point, like

```
SELECT * from posts
WHERE posts.id NOT IN (
   SELECT posts.id FROM posts JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id)
```

As my database has grown this query has gotten substantially worse. I'm not great at SQL; is there a better way to do this? I'm using ActiveRecord, if that helps/hurts.

Comment: ActiveRecord almost always hurts ;-) . Details please, in particular your PostgreSQL version and the output of `explain analyze` on the problem query.

Comment: How should points 2 and 3 look like? Aggregate `comments` into single column or duplicate `post` columns for each comment?

Comment: Your point 3. doesn't make sense. You are mixing the terms "post" and "comment". Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Debug presented query

The query you presented is unnecessarily inefficient. First, you can simplify by leaving away the redundant JOIN in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  posts.id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM comments)
```

And this can be rewritten as `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or with an [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-antijoin, which I expect to perform best:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM comments c WHERE c.post_id = p.id)
```

#### Full query

Your point 3. is unclear:

> Does include that 10 most recent comments on that post.

Ignoring that one, the query could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts p
WHERE  p.author_id <> $author_id -- "not a post by that author"
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   comments c
   WHERE  c.author_id = $author_id
   AND    c.post_id = p.id) -- exclude "post that has a comment by that author"
--  ORDER  BY ??undefined??, maybe id DESC
LIMIT  20
```

`posts.author_id` should be defined `NOT NULL` or you have to use:

```
p.author_id IS DISTINCT FROM $author_id
```

With lots of rows, **indexes** are the key to performance. I expect `posts.id` to be the primary key, so it's indexed automatically. Add this multicolumn index if you don't have it, yet:

```
CREATE INDEX comments_pa_idx ON comments (post_id, author_id);
```

Comment: This got me on the right track. Problem was with an OFFSET, which I removed for a speedup. Couldn't figure out how to optimize with the OFFSET in, but breaking down the query as you suggested got me that far.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with  this one

```
SELECT * from posts p, comments c
WHERE posts.id <> c.posts.id;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that "not in" kills query times more than anything.  Alternatives are "not exists" or, if postgresql supports this syntax.

```
where somefield in 
(select somefield
 from etc
 except
 select somefield
 from etc)
```

Sometimes the word minus is used instead of except.